# Publish Docker Compose Container to cloud

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, azure, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file that contains .net API, Postgresql, Redis, and Minio. They have volumes to persist the data.

On my local machine, I can simply call docker compose up to run the container. However, I am not sure how to deploy this to public using Azure, AWS, or etc.

I tried Azure and AWS, but I wasn't sure how to publish a compose file with volume.

Also, I want to publish the API, but have access to the postgresql. I want to connect to postgresql separately to maintain it. Therefore, I think the best bet is to get a cloud vm and port forward the api to public. However, this method, does not recognize other docker images as they also live in localhost.

I need a simple maintainable way to deploy docker compose file with volume. Any suggestions?

Below is my docker compose file for reference

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  # livecheck_frontend:
  #   container_name: livecheck_frontend
  #   image: livecheck_frontend:latest
  #   build:
  #     context: ./frontend
  #     dockerfile: Dockerfile
  #   ports:
  #     - "80:80"

  livecheck_backend:
    container_name: livecheck_backend
    image: livecheck_backend:latest
    restart: always
    # build:
    #   context: ./backend
    #   dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=User ID=postgres;Password=postgres;Server=livecheck_postgres;Port=5432;Database=LiveCheckDB;IntegratedSecurity=true;Pooling=true;
      - ConnectionStrings__MinioConnection=livecheck_minio:9000
      - ConnectionStrings__RedisConnection=livecheck_redis:6379
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    depends_on:
      - livecheck_postgres
      - livecheck_minio
      - livecheck_redis
  
  livecheck_postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine3.17
    container_name: livecheck_postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=LiveCheckDB
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  livecheck_redis:
    image: redis:alpine3.17
    container_name: livecheck_redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data

  livecheck_minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio:RELEASE.2023-03-22T06-36-24Z
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
    container_name: livecheck_minio
    expose:
      # Server
      - "9000"
      # Console
      - "9001"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: miniominio
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: miniominio
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - ./data/minio:/data

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.2-alpine
    hostname: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      # minio Server
      - "9000:9000"
      # minio console
      - "9001:9001"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - livecheck_minio


volumes:
  livecheck_postgres:
  livecheck_minio:
  livecheck_redis:
```